# How is Android Studio Navigation Drawer navigating different Fragments?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I've been trying to figure out how the default Navigation Drawer Activity template came with Android Studio navigates between different fragments. I understand that this menu is an implementation using AndroidX navigation component and navigation graph, but I just cannot understand how each menu item is mapped to its corresponding fragment. I don't see any listener or onNavigationItemSelected() etc. Can someone explain how the mapping between menuItem and corresponding fragment was achieved?

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                navController.getGraph())
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();

        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

menu.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="@string/menu_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="@string/menu_gallery" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="@string/menu_slideshow" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

nav_graph.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="com.buzzz.myapplication.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_HomeFragment_to_HomeSecondFragment"
            app:destination="@id/nav_home_second" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home_second"
        android:name="com.buzzz.myapplication.ui.home.HomeSecondFragment"
        android:label="@string/home_second"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home_second">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_HomeSecondFragment_to_HomeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/nav_home" />

        <argument
            android:name="myArg"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:name="com.buzzz.myapplication.ui.gallery.GalleryFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_gallery"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_gallery" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:name="com.buzzz.myapplication.ui.slideshow.SlideshowFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_slideshow"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_slideshow" />
</navigation>
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Update UI components with NavigationUI documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui), the `setupWithNavController()` methods hook up UI elements (such as your `NavigationView`) with the NavController.

Looking at the [`setupWithNavController()` Javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI#setupWithNavController(com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView,%20androidx.navigation.NavController)):

> Sets up a `NavigationView` for use with a `NavController`. This will call [`onNavDestinationSelected`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI#onNavDestinationSelected(android.view.MenuItem,%20androidx.navigation.NavController)) when a menu item is selected. The selected item in the `NavigationView` will automatically be updated when the destination changes.

So internally, this is setting up the appropriate listeners - both on the `NavigationView` to handle menu selections and on the `NavController` to update the selected item when the current destination changes.

Looking at the [`onNavDestinationSelected()` Javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI#onNavDestinationSelected(android.view.MenuItem,%20androidx.navigation.NavController)), it becomes clear how the menu items and navigation graph destinations are matched:

> Importantly, it assumes the [menu item id](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#getItemId()) matches a valid [action id](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavDestination#getAction(int)) or [destination id](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavDestination#getId()) to be navigated to.

So clicking on a menu item with `android:id="@+id/nav_home"` will navigate to the destination with `android:id="@+id/nav_home"`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explaination. It is really helpful!